# Sidebar as 'nav' or 'header' when making site?

Tags: wordpress, header, navigation

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I'm currently working on a WordPress theme and I plan on creating the navigation section as a sidebar.

**My problem**:

I still don't know how to approach this: should I make the sidebar a nav element or the header? I'm asking because the sidebar is one thing, but there is also this other part in my content that is similar to a header (one h1 text and a background image) and I'm not sure if that should be the header instead of my sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on what @THN said, when it comes to WordPress I would differentiate your nav from a sidebar, as that's a standard theme element, i.e. `sidebar.php`.

Perhaps a good approach would be to have your container (i.e. what you refer to as the sidebar), with something like the following:

```
<body>
<section class="your-sidebar">
    <header role="banner"><a href="/">Your logo</a></header>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul role="menu">
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
<main role="main">
    <!-- Main content here -->
</main>
</body>
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way, but if you plan on using widgets then it'd be best to do a sidebar.